# prove that $10200300040000100004000300201$ is not perfect square

Tags: number-theory

How can I prove that $ 10200300040000100004000300201$ is not a perfect square ? This number is divisible with $3$ only one time. Is it a good reason and it is enough ?

thanks :)

Comment: yes. If $3|n$ and $n$ is a perfect square, then $9|n$.

Comment: In fact, $10200300040000100004000300201= 3 · 23 · 1613867 · 91600135179863204287$ has no square factors.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes. Assume by contradiction that your number is a perfect square $n^2$.

Since $3|n \cdot n$ and $3$ is prime, it follows that $3|n$. Then $n=3k$ and hence
$n^2=9k^2$. Thus, your number is divisible by $9$, contradiction.

Comment: How does the fact that it is divisible by 9 mean that it is not a perfect square?

Comment: @S.Mo That's the contradiction. This number is divisible by 3 but NOT divisible by 9.

Comment: Ah, I see, didn't notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Assume the distinct prime factors of $n$ are $p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_k$, as:

$$n = p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$$

For $n$ to be a perfect square, a necessary and sufficient condition is $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_k$ even, such that $\sqrt{p_i^{\alpha_i}}$ be an integer $\implies$ $\sqrt{n}$ be an integer. Otherwise, $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational and hence $n$ is not a perfect square.

---

If $3$ divides $n$ *only one time*, then we must have:

$$n = 3^1 p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$$

$1$ is not even, therefore $n$ is not a perfect square.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** $ 3|n \wedge (n=k^2,k\in\mathbb{N})$ follows that $9|n$.

**HINT 2:** Use the divisibility test of $9$.

Answer (score 2):

The [digital root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root#Some_properties_of_digital_roots) of a square is $1, 4, 7$, or $9$. Yours is $3$...